# pgAdmin4: An error message appears before app successfully loads and opens in Windows 10, what to do?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-application, node-webkit, pgadmin-4, postgresql-15

[image: Popup appears before pgadmin4 app loads and opens]

Some more details to help you guys see what is exactly the problem.

```
pgAdmin4: 7.4
Chromium: 92.0.4515.107
PostgreSQL: 15
NW.js: 0.55.0
OS: Windows 10-10.0.19045-SP0
```

Related problem (I think):
I am developing a node.js API that connects to a created server in pgAdmin4 at port 5432. Whenever I open and start the same server in the desktop application it says 'server connection timeout'. I tried extending the timeout settings into a minute at most and its the same results. Vice versa, starting the API in CMD would return 'EACCES' error. The only time I would solve this problem from the API side would be to kill the PID that uses 127.0.0.1:5432 address and port on CMD. Lately I cannot open the server from the admin app with or without the node.js API connected to localhost using port 5432. Do you guys think this problem is related to the question? I hope I can hit two birds with one stone.

For the main problem, I accessed the location of log file and a certain 'werkzeug' appears. Here is the exact message before the 'connection timeout' error logs.

```
2023-08-15 15:37:51,088: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.
2023-08-15 15:37:51,090: WARNING    werkzeug:   Werkzeug appears to be used in a production deployment. Consider switching to a production web server instead.
2023-08-15 15:41:39,540: ERROR  pgadmin:    Could not connect to server(#2) - 'ai-radio-server'.
Error: connection timeout expired
2023-08-15 15:42:00,568: ERROR  pgadmin:    Could not connect to server(#2) - 'ai-radio-server'.
```